# Why calling Excel from Oracle Forms on the Citrix Receiver does not work?

Tags: excel, oracle11g, oracleforms

I have used webutil feature to copy the data from Excel into my Oracle forms. It works fine when I run the forms on my local machine (from Oracle Forms Builder), and when I install it on the linux server.
But I am not able to copy the data from excel when I call the forms from Citrix. The program stops when the control arrives to

> application := client_OLE2.create_obj('Excel.Application');

(It will not help if I replace client_ole2 with ole2)

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run this on Cirtix we figured out that the related libraries i.e. d2kwut60.dll, JNIsharedstubs.dll, and jacob.dll must to be copied on c:/program file/ java/ jre6.

:-)